# Nginx + Passenger turn on gzip not take effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, gzip, passenger

Try to turn on Nginx gzip feature to save some bandwidth, but no luck.
Searching for hours still can not make it work.

Nginx is installed by Passenger. Here is the information about Nginx in my server:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --add-module=/home/lijc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3.2/gems/passenger-4.0.2/ext/nginx
```

Nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;  
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
passenger_root /home/lijc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3.2/gems/passenger-4.0.2;
passenger_ruby /home/lijc/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3.2/ruby;

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on; 
client_max_body_size 100m;
keepalive_timeout  65; 

gzip                                on; 
gzip_min_length                     1k; 
gzip_disable                        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
gzip_http_version                   1.1;
gzip_types                          text/plain text/css application/x-javascript application/xml application/json application/atom+xml application/rss+xml;
gzip_vary                           on; 

server {
    listen       80; 
    server_name  localhost;

    root /home/lijc/web/rails/jasli2team/evolution/public;
    passenger_enabled on; 
}
}
```

Then restart Nginx and Passenger. However with Chrome dev tools. The header return by my site still not including `Content-Encoding:gzip`

Here is the header return by my site:

```
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 05 Jun 2013 02:55:47 GMT
ETag:"f5a1b272c96c5786342ec4bfd9b6e608"
Proxy-Connection:close
Server:nginx/1.4.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.2
Status:200 OK
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.0 localhost.localdomain:1080 (squid/2.6.STABLE16)
X-Cache:MISS from localhost.localdomain
X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from localhost.localdomain:1080
X-Powered-By:Phusion Passenger 4.0.2
X-Rack-Cache:miss
X-Request-Id:8353874387ca7510158dd5bf93b37ab9
X-Runtime:0.042863
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

I have no idea what is wrong or missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a silly double check, but did you test with a file that was at least 1k? Did you get a content-length header?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: thanks for you reply. I checked the header again. For html page, no content-length in header. But in css/javascript file, http header dose contains the content-length. Does this matter? Sorry, I'm not familiar with HTTP protocol.

Comment: The setting is that it won't compress files below 1kB, if it does not know the length, it may not compress the file.

Comment: The html file is larger than 1K and I tried to remove the file limitation in nginx.conf. But the issue remains the same.

Comment: FWIW it seems to work ok here for assets at least... http://freeldssheetmusic.org/javascripts/default.js?1290527792 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch (though the only option I specify is gzip on; none of the rest...)